# Ubuntu 18.04 large amount of available or unallocated memory?

Tags: ram

Ubuntu 18.04 large amount of available or unallocated memory?

This is related to my prior question. I have 32gb of RAM installed on this Ryzen 2700x system. BIOS detects the RAM, everything should be all good. `# lshw -C memory` shows 32gb of RAM present in Ubuntu. The crux of the issue is that the system is only showing ~16gb of RAM total.

I've come across some new commands, which I've shown the output of below. They seem to indicate that roughly 1gb RAM is cached and roughly 14 gb of RAM is 'available' but not allocated for use. When adding these to the `MemTotal` we would get roughly 32gb I think. I'm interpreting `MemFree` as the amount of allocated RAM that is available but waiting to be used from the `MemTotal`.

My interpretation could be wildly wrong, but please let me know if you have any advice.

`# watch -n 1 free -m`

[image: OUTPUT watch -n 1 free -m]

`# watch -n 1 cat /proc/meminfo`

[image: OUTPUT # watch -n 1 cat /proc/meminfo]